# console.log(a==b); и console.log(new A() == new B()); выводят false или true?

Tags: javascript, объекты

https://learn.javascript.ru/constructor-new#tasks В этой задаче alert( a == b ); там написали что выводит true. Но я проверила код, выводится false. Для проверки я сама тоже написала код(ниже), там тоже выводится false.

```js
function A(name, job){
  this.name=name;
  this.job=job;
  this.display=function(){
    console.log(this.name+" is a "+this.job);
  };
}
function B(name, job){
  this.name=name;
  this.job=job; 
  this.display=function(){
    console.log(this.name+" is a "+this.job);
  };
}

let a= new A("Mike", "teacher");
let b= new B("Mike", "teacher");
a.display();
b.display();
console.log(a==b); //false
console.log( new A() == new B() ); //false
```

```js
let obj = {
  display:function(){
    console.log(this.name+" is a "+this.job);
  },
  };

function A(name, job){
  return obj;
};
function B(name, job){
 return obj;
};

let a= new A("Mike", "teacher");
let b= new B("Mike", "teacher");
a.display(); //'undefined is a undefined'
b.display(); //'undefined is a undefined'
console.log(a==b); //true
console.log( new A() == new B() ); //true
```

Comment: Где у вас `return obj`? Там же дается пояснение, когда такое возможно. Вы его читали?

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko Да, я прочла всё(видимо невнимательно). Ошибку поняла. Тот же код я поменяла так чтобы она вывела true. Выводится true, но a.display(); выводит 'undefined is a undefined'. Что я там неправильно написала?(Вставила код выше)

Comment: Вы не записываете никуда name и job. Можно перед `return obj;` их записывать `obj.name=name; obj.job=job;`